# How to get the xml data from c# and show it as list in html using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, xml, asp.net-web-api

I am getting xml data from web api controller in c#. I need to show this data as list in html view page. I tried various methods but none of them is working.
Here is the XML Data which i am getting from api. Suggest a way how it can be done.
Thanks in advance.

```
<ArrayOfIDValue xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IFlicksAPI.Controllers">
  <IDValue>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Shuba</Name>
  </IDValue>
  <IDValue>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Raji</Name>
 </IDValue>
 <IDValue>
   <ID>3</ID>
   <Name>Renu</Name>
 </IDValue>
</ArrayOfIDValue>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can parse the xml and iterate through all the items

```
success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('IDValue').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).find("ID").text();
                var name = $(this).find("name").text();
                $("#list").append("<option value='" + id + "'>" + name + "</option>")
            });
        }
```

ofcource you need to use jQuery ajax function with your web api url

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class using xml.serialiation and serialize the xml data in to an object of that class, 
then just fill the list as it must be done

example: the xml template class

using System.Xml.Serialization;

```
namespace App
{
[XmlRoot("GuiConfig")]
public class ConfigParameters
{
    [XmlElement("field1")]
    public string field1;

    [XmlElement("field2")]
    public string field2;
}
```

how to serialize

```
public static void GetXmlData() 
    {
        config = new ConfigParameters(); //global scope var
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists("C:/path/config.xml"))
            {
                String xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("C:/path/config.xml").ToString();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new 
XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigParameters));
                using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlDoc))
                {
                    mainForm.config = 
(ConfigParameters)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```